# Yahoo search has taken over Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-search

Somehow Yahoo has been added as the default search provider in Firefox. How can I get rid of it and go back to Google?

I recently installed the "Tab Mix Plus" Firefox extension, so I suspect that this has changed the search provider.

When I enter a set of words which, without the "www", I used to get the proper URL. Now, I get some sort of search which returns nothing close to what I was looking for and proudly proclaims itself to be "Yahoo Search"

I liked Google before and I would like to return to using Google for search. I have looked all through "Add/Remove Programs" in the Windows XP control panel, but it's not there.

Comment: Wait… I am confused. Is the Firefox search box up in the top right hand corner using Yahoo for its search now, or are you talking about the Awesome Bar (address bar)?

Comment: No, he's talking about the Awesome Bar.  the search box default probably also got changed, but that's easy to change back.  typical of 3rd-party browser toolbars -- FreeCause has a themable toolbar that's used in a lot of places and does exactly that.  this is not Tab Mix Plus.  you may have agreed to install some browser toolbar as part of another program's installer.

Comment: Screenshot, just in case there's more info on that page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to change the default search engine for the address bar. Follow this [post](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-change-your-firefox-location-bar-search-engine/).
Alternatively you can set the keyword as mentioned in the post to the below value which is present in my browser:

> http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=

Comment: +1 nice solution.  **beware** if you do this without uninstalling whatever changed it in the first place, it might get changed back at a later point.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a malware plugin "Search Settings Plugin" that was installed without knowledge of the user.  Uninstall that plugin and it should fix the problem.  You still need to update the about:config to restore to original settings.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your OS.  Under Windows, you may have to go to Control Panel >> Programs (or Add/Remove Programs) and remove the Yahoo! toolbar that way.  Also, in Firefox click Tools >> Add-Ons and remove any Yahoo! plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The **McAfee Site Advisor** addon does this. I'm pretty certain all of you have it installed.
Here's the proof. This is what the keyword looks like in my about:config
`http://in.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&p=`
Notice the McAfee at the end?

It seems that this behaviour can only be changed with the Plus version of the toolbar. I haven't restarted the browser yet, so  can't comment whether MASA will change it back to yahoo or not.
And thanks for helping me find the problem.